# Setting up subdomains in local xampp

Tags: apache

I need to set subdomain in xampp local machine.

is this possible?

aaa.project1 should point to C:/xampp/htdocs/project1
bbb.project1 should point to C:/xampp/htdocs/project1

and so on dynamically.

I tried different options i couldn't achieve. Please help .

This is what i did in my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/"
ServerName project1
ServerAlias *.project1 project1
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And i put an entry in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1  project1
127.0.0.1  *.project1
```

Comment: Have your read any tutorial on how to setup a virtual host on apache? http://www.apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php or is the problem the dynamic part?

Comment: Evrything worked perfect expect the dynamic. I can set up statis subdomains by putting an entry but *.domain name seems not working

Comment: Checkout this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
127.0.0.1  project1
127.0.0.1  aaa.project1
127.0.0.1  bbb.project1
```